# Is it ok if query a sqlite inside recyclerview.adapter?

Tags: android-sqlite, android-recyclerview

I wanted to query a sqlite, for each of row being processed. Take up some element as params, then query a sqlite. Is it ok or bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

Generally that'll be too slow... take a look at `CursorAdapters`.
Here's [a little tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/fmavhg/android-cursoradapter-with-custom-layout-and-how-to-use-it).